# Docker MongoDB container not starting properly - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017

Tags: mongodb, docker, mongodb-compass

I'm new to Docker and am attempting to run a container using the mongo image and connect to it using MongoDBCompass.

The command I'm using to start the container, which was modified from the [image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo) is:

`docker run --name some-mongo -d  mongo -p 27017:27017`

This results in the container exiting straight away. I noticed this when trying to connect from MongoDBCompass gave the error message **connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017**.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me modify the run command to keep the container running and allow me to connect using MongoDBCompass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the `docker run` command, options are split in two groups.

- options before the image name are docker options
- options after the image name are sent as a command to the container

You have `-p 27017:27017` after the image name, so it's sent as a command to the container. Mongo doesn't understand that command, so it exits with an error.
Place the port mapping options before the image name and it'll work. Like this

```
docker run --name some-mongo -d -p 27017:27017 mongo
```